# Spring Security integration with remote Authentication Provider (SAML)

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, saml-2.0

I'm trying to integrate my Spring app with governmental system responsible for user's authentication (SAML). The main concept is that "my" app is receiving already logged user with so called assertion. And the point is how can I customize Spring Security to recognize mentioned before assertion as proof that user is authenticated. Or maybe should I write my own filters instead of using Spring Security?

Unfortunately I can't share the code - company policy ;(
Any feedback is appreciated.

Maciek

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a SAML assertion (it's easy to see, it's a whole XML packet), you absolutely need a library to deal with that complexity.

[pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org/) (security engine for Java) supports the SAML protocol. So either you keep Spring Security and use the pac4j extension for Spring Security: [spring-security-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-security-pac4j) or you directly use the pac4j security libraries for Spring MVC/Boot: [spring-webmvc-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/spring-webmvc-pac4j) or for J2E: [j2e-pac4j](https://github.com/pac4j/j2e-pac4j) for example.